# Replace file extension from filename.tex.aux to filename.aux

Tags: string

I have a bunch of latex genererated outputs

filename1.tex.aux
filename1.tex.log 
and so on, 
filename2.tex.aux
filename2.tex.log

How can I remove the .tex. in the middle? and do it recursively for all the files in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-purposed a perl program I had the removes spaces from file names.
It seems to do the job.

-------begin perl script rename_files.pl--------------
    #!/usr/bin/env perl

```
#
#  Danny K c) 2014
#  qdtk41@gmail.com
#
#
use strict;
use Cwd;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::DosGlob;

#
# needed for windows shell
#
@ARGV = map {
    my @g = File::DosGlob::glob($_) if /[*?]/;
    @g ? @g : $_;
} @ARGV;


my %options;

getopts( 'hrye', \%options );

if ( $options{h} or !@ARGV ) { &usage() and exit; }

foreach my $argument (@ARGV) 
{
    &renameFiles($argument) if (-d $argument) ;
    &_renameFiles($argument) if (-f $argument); 
}

sub renameFiles {
    my $theCurDir = getcwd();    # get the current directory
    my $theDir    = shift;       # get the input directory

    chdir $theDir || return "unable to change to $theDir : $!\n";

    # open the current directory for reading
    opendir( THIS, '.' ) || die "unable to open directory ";

    # that don't start with '.'

    my @allTheFiles = readdir THIS;

    # close the directory for reading
    closedir THIS;

    my @thefiles = grep { !/^\./ } @allTheFiles; 

    # flag to recurse into any directories
    if ( $options{r} ) {
        foreach my $arg (@thefiles) {
            &renameFiles($arg) if ( -d $arg ); 
        }
    }

    # get the files with 'tex'
    my @files = grep { /tex/i } @thefiles;

    print "\n\n", $theCurDir, "/", $theDir, "\n" if ( $options{e} and @files );

    # loop through all the names found
    &_renameFiles(@files);
    chdir $theCurDir;    # go back to the original directory
}

sub _renameFiles {
    my @files = @_;
    foreach (@files) {
        my $currentFile = $_;    # save the current file
    s/(.*?)(\.tex)(\..*?)$/$1$3/i;
        # rename the file within perl
        if ( $_ ne $currentFile ) {
            if ( -e $_ ) {
                print "$_ exists already. Will NOT : rename $currentFile to $_\n";
            }
            else {
                rename $currentFile, $_ if ( $options{y} );
                print "rename $currentFile, $_\n";
            }
        }
    }

}

sub usage {

    my $sp = "    ";

    print "\n";
    print $sp, "rename_files [options] (files or directories)\n";
    print $sp, "*** No file will be rename without the 'y' option\n\n";

    print $sp, "usage:  rename_files -reyh [ file &/or directories or wildcards ]\n";
    print $sp, "    r  - recurse into subdirectories\n";
    print $sp, "    e  - print the current directory\n";
    print $sp, "    y  - execute the rename command\n";
    print $sp, "    h  - usage statement\n";

}
```

-------end perl script rename_files.pl--------------

```
Using a bash shell and perl and given:

examples/here/there/everywhere/1.tEx.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/2.tEx.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/3.tEx.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/4.tEx.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/5.tEx.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere.Tex.txt
examples/here/there.tex.log
examples/here.tex.dat

Resulting command:
perl rename_files.pl -r examples

Commands that would get executed:
rename 1.tEx.doc, 1.doc
rename 2.tEx.doc, 2.doc
rename 3.tEx.doc, 3.doc
rename 4.tEx.doc, 4.doc
rename 5.tEx.doc, 5.doc
rename everywhere.Tex.txt, everywhere.txt
rename there.tex.log, there.log
rename here.tex.dat, here.dat


Resulting files if  perl rename_files.pl -yre examples 

$ find examples -type f
examples/here/there/everywhere/1.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/2.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/3.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/4.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere/5.doc
examples/here/there/everywhere.txt
examples/here/there.log
examples/here.dat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I appreciate the effort in putting up this program. I am completely new to perl. 

Could you show me how I can use it?

Comment: copy the script which is between the begin & end statements into a text file and call it what you want but use the extension '.pl'  in linux/unix in a shell execute: 'perl [script name] -h' and the options will be displayed.  I also placed an example.  If you are in windows, you'll have to install perl.  activestate perl or strawberry perl are enough. you can google each of these perls to get their download locations. After you have perl, open a cmd window and use the same command.  Notice the '-y' option.  email if you have questions.

Comment: +1, thank you, it works great. I wanted to change 
fileName.tex.doc to fileName.doc i.e. remove the .tex. Could you help me out ?

Comment: sorry about that.  give me a minute

Comment: change this line:  s/(.*?)(\.tex)(\..*?)$/$1$2/i;
to s/(.*?)(\.tex)(\..*?)$/$1$3/i;

Comment: thanks a ton, initially, feeding fileName.tex.log to sed using "ls -l | sed 's/.*\.//'" I got log as output, I have no clue how I can do in file by file perhaps using "basename"

Comment: Nope, I am trying it out though. I will post it once it works